# why would radarchart() produce empty graphs

Tags: radar-chart

I am trying to plot some radar graphs but I have spend the whole day searching and I dont seem to get where I am getting my code wrong as I am getting empty graphs.
I used the `library(fmsb)`
My data is as

```
df<-data.frame(
site.spp=c("G.E", "G.R", "N.E", "N.R","W.R"),
am1=c(11.17, 62.71, 14, 17, 23),
am2=c(5.75,62.9,20.18,18,8.375),
pm1=c(16.14, 53.77, 21.75, 53, 25.67),
pm2=c(20, 52.5, 34.2, 23.38, 4.75)
)
```

I tried to set my graph margins, and then run a loop.

```
par(mar=c(2, 1, 2, 1))
layout(matrix(1:6, ncol=3)) #draw 4 plots to device

lapply(1:5, function(i) { 
  radarchart(rbind(rep(1,6), rep(0,6), df[i,-1]))
})
```

I am only getting empty graphs without the plotting of my data. Would someone help this beginer?

Comment: Or did I get my par() wrong? I have been trying but nothing seems to improve

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I was just not setting the ranges for my plot right,

So it works perfectly I change the range of the plots from rep (0-6) to rep(0-70) -to cover the range my data. I thought this might help other beginners like me!

```
lapply(1:5, function(i) { 
  radarchart(rbind(rep(70,4), rep(0,4), df[i,-1]))
})
```